# Why part of HandlerThread's run() method is synchronized?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronized, android-handler

I'm going thru [HandlerThread](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/HandlerThread.java) source code and I can't understand why part of HandlerThread's run() method is synchronized?

```
@Override
public void run() {
    mTid = Process.myTid();
    Looper.prepare();
    synchronized (this) {
        mLooper = Looper.myLooper();
        notifyAll();
    }
    Process.setThreadPriority(mPriority);
    onLooperPrepared();
    Looper.loop();
    mTid = -1;
}
```

I thought that the `run()` method is called on the thread it belongs to so how can it be reached from multiple threads?

I expect it has sth to do with the situation when somebody create and start multiple instances of the same HandlerThread class.

Comment: Maybe other threads lock on that `Thread` instance? (that's generally a bad idea)

Comment: This may be it as in other part of that class there is "// If the thread has been started, wait until the looper has been created.
        synchronized (this) {".

Comment: This is just a guess (I don't know android), but it looks like some other thread might call `handlerThread.wait();` waiting for the value of `mLooper` to change.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is synchronized is that it is required in order to call `notifyAll`.

See the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()):

> This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of
>   this object's monitor. A thread becomes the owner of the object's
>   monitor in one of three ways:
>
> - **By executing a synchronized instance method of that object.**
> - By executing the body of a synchronized statement that synchronizes on the object.
> - For objects of type Class, by executing a synchronized static method of that class.
>
> Only one thread at a time can own an object's monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The caller of `notifyAll()` must hold a lock on the object, so that's why that statement is in the `synchronized` block.  The assignment of `mLooper` is synchronized to ensure that the write is visible to other threads, specifically the caller(s) of `HandlerThread#getLooper()`, which contains this code:

```
    // If the thread has been started, wait until the looper has been created.
    synchronized (this) {
        while (isAlive() && mLooper == null) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getLooper()` method is supposed to return the `Looper` instance connected to the `HandlerThread`. Also this getter should be thread-safe for obvious reasons. So the implementation *waits* indefinitely, while the `run()` methods notifies all waiting threads after `mLooper` is setup.

```
public void run() {
    ...
    synchronized (this) {
        mLooper = Looper.myLooper();
        notifyAll();
    }
    ...
}

public Looper getLooper() {
    ...
    synchronized (this) {
        while (isAlive() && mLooper == null) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return mLooper;
}
```

The synchronized blocks are the minimal parts of the code to require the intrinsic lock which the `wait()` method suspends.